# Using a letsencrypt certificate in a java web server

Tags: java, ssl, https, lets-encrypt, undertow

I opted to use [acme4j](https://shredzone.org/maven/acme4j/usage/certificate.html) to create a letsencrypt certificate.  So far it seems to have worked perfectly and I have some java code that creates a registration, responds to a challenge an ultimately presents me with a x509 certificate for my domain (along with a 'certificate chain').  The code is integrated nicely into my java application and doesn't require any downtime for certificate renewal. Awesome.

From here I'm a bit stuck.  My application is a just a *main* app that has an embedded undertow webserver that I instantiate programatically.  In order to create an https listener I need to create an *SSLContext* object.   I've saved the x509 certificate that I got from letsencrypt to disk so it can be reused:

```
    ...
    X509Certificate x509 = cert.download();

    Path pemFile = pathTo(domain + ".pem");

    try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(pemFile); JcaPEMWriter jcaPEMWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(writer)) {
        jcaPEMWriter.writeObject(x509);
    }
```

And then on start up my application reloads that certificate and passes it into the undertow web server:

```
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    FileInputStream finStream = new FileInputStream(certFile.toFile());
    X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(finStream);

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("someAlias", x509Certificate);

    TrustManagerFactory instance = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    instance.init(keyStore);

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, instance.getTrustManagers(), null);
    SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);

    Undertow.Builder builder = Undertow.builder();
    builder.addHttpsListener(httpsPort, ipAddress, sslContext);
```

The app starts, can't see any errors or warnings until I try and hit an https endpoint where Chrome just shows _ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED_.  I turned on `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to try and see whats going on:

```
%% Initialized:  [Session-12, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
XNIO-1 task-12, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-12, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
XNIO-1 task-12, SEND TLSv1.1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
XNIO-1 task-12, WRITE: TLSv1.1 Alert, length = 2
XNIO-1 I/O-2, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
XNIO-1 I/O-2, called closeInbound()
XNIO-1 I/O-2, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
2016-09-08 08:34:46,861 DEBUG [io] - UT005013: An IOException occurred
java.io.IOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
```

I'm trying to come up with a pure java solution here.  Something that is repeatable, in code and can be tested and checked in to source control.  I want to avoid having to do any out-of-jvm machine level set up if possible.

After lots of hackery and reading, it seems like I need to use the `keytool` and some combination of the certificate I was issued, along with the certificate chain I was issued, along with the root certificate and some/none/all of the intermediate [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) certificates! Seriously?

I tried following the instructions [here](https://pubs.vmware.com/continuent/tungsten-replicator-3.0/deployment-ssl-stores.html) from the section titled "7.3.1.3. Using an existing Certificate" but only to end up with exactly the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

An SSL/TLS server (in any language) requires a PRIVATE KEY AND certificate (and nearly always a cert chain) not just a certificate. And a *Java* SSL/TLS server needs that privatekey+certchain in a KeyManager not a TrustManager -- any advice that recommended you set only a TrustManager for an SSL/TLS server is totally incompetent. The section 7.3.1.3 you link to makes no sense, although the *next* section 7.3.1.4, although it claims a bug I have never seen and I have used just about every version of OpenSSL, *does* describe *almost* the right way to convert *OpenSSL* key+cert to Java, which matches the earlier sections which described creating keys and certs in OpenSSL format. But you don't have OpenSSL format.

[That acme4j page](https://shredzone.org/maven/acme4j/usage/certificate.html) 
correctly says you should "generate a separate pair of keys" -- pair meaning private and public -- which the earlier "How to Use" page told you how to do with their `KeyPairUtils`, then generate a CSR and send it in, and get the certificate and chain. It specifies a single call

```
X509Certificate[] chain = cert.downloadChain()
```

which might be what you need if LetsEncrypt is clever; look at `chain[0].getSubjectX500Principal()` and see if it's you. If not you probably need to do both `download()` and `downloadChain()` and put them together in one array with your cert first:

```
X509Certificate[] fixchain = new X509Certificate [chain.length+1];
fixchain[0] = mycert; System.arraycopy (chain,0, fixchain,1, chain.length);
chain = fixchain; // for simplicity
```

Once you have the cert chain AND the key pair, do something like

```
char[] password = /* some value, should be secure if used for file, 
    if used only in memory doesn't really matter */
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks"/*or default if you don't care*/); 
ks.load (null); // above line and this same as you have now
ks.setKeyEntry ("alias", keypair.getPrivateKey(), password, chain);
// this line different -- KeyEntry not CertificateEntry

// if you want to save in a file for reuse
try( OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream ("blah") ){ ks.store (os, password); }
// if you want to save somewhere else, extrapolate 

// if/when you want to run server
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(ks, password); // same password as above (or when stored)
// MAYBE TrustManager if you want to require certs FROM CLIENTS
// in which case the certs you trust probably shouldn't be limited to LetsEncrypt
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS";
ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null /*or tmf.getTrustManagers()*/, null);
SSLContext.setDefault (ctx); // or otherwise use ctx
```

FYI if a certificate had actually been what you needed to store and read, you don't need to convert it to PEM unless you want people to cut&paste etc. Java `CertificateFactory` has handled both DER and PEM for at least a decade.